# What is this string on the 737?

Tags: aircraft-design, boeing-737

The other day I was spotting at Miami International ([MIA/KMIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami_International_Airport)) and noticed something hanging out of the fuselage.

A man with a green jacket is holding a device attached to a cable. Can somebody determine what that is?

[image]

Comment: That's the **leash**,  some cities require all airplanes to be leashed any time they are on the ground and require the operators to pick up after the planes as well.

Comment: @dotancohen If a 737 did the sort of things that need picking up on my lawn, I too would hope that someone actually picks up after it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ground crew has connected a headset to the communication jack outsiede for flight pushback communication with the flight crew. from [b737.org.uk](http://www.b737.org.uk/communications.htm):

> The External Power Hatch is located beneath the F/O's DV window. It is used by groundcrew to connect the Ground Power Unit and headset for pushback communications with Flight Interphone.
>
> The service interphone is used by engineers to communicate with the service interphone stations inside the aircraft.

Here is a closeup of the connection point

[image: Comm]

Image from [b737.org.uk](http://www.b737.org.uk/communications.htm)

About [flight interphone System](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNqrTSn8vKAhWDcY4KHWNVAK0QFggqMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartcockpit.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fpath%3Ddocs%2F%26file%3DB_NG-Communications.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE2cujG-G4lSlvpIYAagNEUBM0Y_A&bvm=bv.112766941,d.c2E)

> The flight interphone system is an independent communication network. Its
> primary purpose is to provide private communication between flight deck
> crewmembers without intrusion from the service interphone system. The ground
> crew may also use the flight interphone through a jack at the external power
> receptacle.

And here is a nose section of 737-200, showing it from a not so close angle.

[image: 737-200]

Image from rigger.smugmug.com